# Getting good timestamps for sensor readings

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I'm trying to get timestamp data to match accelerometer and gyroscope readings.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with python to pull accelerometer (Adxl345) and gyroscope (ITG3200) readings. I'm currently reading them through I2C as fast as I can, and I write a timestamp from the system time (time.time()) immediately before reading.

I thought this would be sufficiently accurate, but when I look at the resulting data the time is often not monotonic and/or just looks wrong. In fact, the result often seem to better match the motion I was tracking if I throw out all but the first timestamp and then synthetically create times based on the frequency of the device I'm collecting from!

That said, this approach clearly gives me wrong data, but I'm at a loss as to where to pull correct data. The accelerometer and gyro don't seem to include times in anything they do, and if I pull data as fast as I can I'm still bound to miss some from them at their highest rates meaning the times I use will always be somewhat wrong.

The accelerometer also has a FIFO cache it can store some values in, but again, if I pull from that case how do I know what timestamp goes with each value?? The documention mentions the cache storing values but nothing about the timestamp.

All of which leads me to believe I'm missing something. Is there a secret here I don't know? Or a standard practice I'm unaware of? Any thoughts or suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: What kind of precision are you looking for?

Comment: How long are you acquring for? And where are you writing the acquired data to?

Comment: The ADXL346 can get up to 1600Hz so around 0.6 milliseconds or better would be the most I'd need, millisecond level would likely be sufficient.

Acquiring for a period of minutes, generally less than 5 but almost certainly less than 30. Writing the data to the SD Card. Also, I've already got a process that stores the data in memory and then spawns new threads to write that to disk every 15k entries so the collection/writing process is fine, it's just a matter of figuring out where to get timestamps from.

Comment: Have you tried `time.perf_counter`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! perf_counter seems to be for timing between consecutive calls of itself, as in for timing code. That and it's also pulled from the pi processor, not the device. In my case I'm trying to get a timestamp for successive data points from another device over multiple minutes. All of that led me to choose time.time() over perf_counter as a better fit for my use case. If there's some other way I'm unaware of which makes perf_counter better then I'm not understanding it and could use a bit more explanation.